# Rcpp: call functions from existing R packages when building cppFunction()

Tags: r, rcpp

I am converting this R function into C++ function using `Rcpp` package. However, since `rdiscrete()` function is from `e1071` package, I am struggling to loading the existing R package and calling the functions from this package.

R function (works fine):

```
library(e1071)
signR <- function(x) {
if (x >= 0) {
rdiscrete(10,c(0.2,0.8),c(5,6))
 } else {
rdiscrete(10,c(0.2,0.8),c(1,2))
 }
}
## Example
signR(2)
```

Rcpp version (error pointed to `rdiscrete` function):

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('int signC(int x) {
if (x >= 0) {
return rdiscrete(10,c(0.2,0.8),c(5,6));
 } else {
return rdiscrete(10,c(0.2,0.8),c(1,2));
 }
}')
```

I appreciate any replies in advance!

Comment: Besides the duplicate, what are you trying to achieve? Calling the function from C++ instead of R won't speed up the code at all.

Comment: In addition to @RalfStubner 's great points about the dupe (there are things there you need to do but aren't to make the R function accessible) and this not speeding up your code at all, there are other things to note: `c()` is not how you create `NumericVector`s; you need `NumericVector::create()`; `int` should not be the return type, but `IntegerVector`; (1/2)

Comment: And most importantly, according to the help file for `rdiscrete()`, "The random number generator is simply a wrapper for sample and provided for backwards compatibility only," so you'd be better off using [RcppArmadillo::sample()](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-the-Rcpp-based-sample-implementation/) (2/2)

Comment: Good job looking at what the function does, @duckmayr. As I recently learned there is also [`Rcpp::sample()`](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/sugar/functions/sample.h).

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions. I will check it out. @RalfStubner, thanks for sharing your thoughts, I am developing some R functions which require to use loops, and using R is very slow so I converted the loops part into C++. However, I was stuck about `rdiscrete()` function so I made up a quick demo example here.